# error: "select command that does not return any key", but Im sure that Im giving a key

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datagridview

Im trying update a table, everything works fine with all my tables but with 1 I have this error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQ75B.jpg

(I cant post images sorry)

and it have a primary key

https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9QJL.jpg

the problem must be in this table because everything works well with any other table, I also tried deleting and creating again the primary key column but the error persist,change the column name neither solves it. If I use this query the sql server can find my primary key so it exist:

```
 SELECT 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(constraint_name), 'IsPrimaryKey') = 1
```

but in the update I still receive the same error:

```
 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Conn1.connectionString);
                    SqlDataAdapter daCust = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Item", con);
                    SqlCommandBuilder cbCust = new SqlCommandBuilder(daCust);
                    daCust.Update(ds.Tables[0]);
```

(I'm sending "ds" to my webserver from a datagridview with all Item columns so it match)

as I said just the table "Item" cant be updated I tried with tens of other tables without problems, and cant understand what I'm doing wrong

Comment: I would try to use [Item] or [dbo.Item] in your query. There's a chance that, in that context, because "Item" is a somewhat "common" word, it could be a reserved word or something of that nature.

Comment: MSDN contains a user post that states that primary keys created after the table is created won't be recognized in your situation. Hope this helps. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5dec5633-ac84-48d9-8fd6-5c7601be4ccd/exception-dynamic-sql-generation-for-the-updatecommand-is-not-supported-against-a-selectcommand?forum=Vsexpressvcs

Comment: I had to delete all the table and creat it again,couldnt find another solution